# How can I mesh a 2D domain with cannot-be-split line segments by using CGAL?

Tags: c++, mesh, cgal, triangulation

I want to use CGAL lib in C++ to mesh a polygonal domain as follows,

[image]

The red line segments should not be split but the black can be split.

What kind of function should I use ? Can you raise a C++ example?

Comment: constrained (delaunay) triangulation, with the red edges as constraints, and with the vertices of the square.

Comment: Thanks! Marc Glisse. After the treatment you proposed, can the domain be divided into a mesh with small triangles (still the constraints cannot be splitt)?

Comment: If there are long constraints, how do you expect to make small triangles without subdividing the constraints?

Comment: I just have a polygon with some small line segments inside the polygon. I just do not want the small segments to be split during meshing. The segments are small enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tradeoff. If the inside line segments are small enough, just add them as constraints without disallowing the splitting. Then, let the min element edge length larger than the length of small segments, before meshing. Generally, the small constraints will not be split.